# One url is able to take two set of parameters ?? (overload simulation) in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to call one function in two way (set of parameters).

like

```
http://exampke.com/test/modea/2017/08/19
http://example.com/test/modeb/tomato
```

if in mode a date value is parameter,

if in mode b vegetable name is parameter.

How do I write this route.yml and controller??

for now I can take only vegetable parameter.

in route.yml

```
acme_member_myfunc:
    path: /test/{mode}/{vegetable}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeMemberBundle:Default:myfuncAction }
```

in myController.php

```
 public function myfuncAction($mode,$vegetable){

 }
```

Comment: Why don't you just write 2 routes? I mean there will be some `if` that will check the mode and then do different thing based on mode, it looks like a better option to have 2 routes here

Comment: Because I would like to call this from one ajax url like 'url : {{path('acme_member_myfunc')}}'

Comment: but you couldn't just do `{{path('acme_member_myfunc')}}` you would still have to check what is the `value` and based on that you should pass the mode. I would go with 2 routes and create a twig macro or a twig function that will return route based on your value.

Comment: Thank to your advice, I change the way , I will make tow route entry and switch by javascript side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use one route, get the mode in twig by

```
{{app.request.get('mode')}}
```

and of course in controller you can change code depending on mode